# Java Thread listening to socket, WHILE loop not waiting

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am creating a `socket` server for a school project. The client is written in `C#` so the `ObjectInputStream` object I have been using so far is not working.

I am now trying to use `InputStreamReader`. In this example, the `while (true)` loop is running at full throttle all the time. Using the `ObjectInputStream` it'd wait for an object to arrive.

How can I do this in a proper way?

```
private InputStreamReader inputStream;

@Override
public void run() {

    while (true) {

        try {

            // ObjectInputStream.read() waits for an object to arrive, 
            // so the execution is paused here

            int data;
            String string = new String();

            while ( (data = inputStream.read() ) != -1) {
                char thisChar = (char) data;
                string = string + thisChar;
            }


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm  pretty sure that inputStream.read() will block until data becomes available. It will return -1 if the stream is closed, and inputStream.ready() will tell you if it has bytes in its buffer or not. The only thing I really see missing from your code is a way for the thread to exit in a controlled manner. So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Uhm, what are you reading exactly? Strings? In what encoding? You should use a `Reader`

Comment: is inputStream ever getting initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the outer loop. It's pointless. The inner loop will run until end of stream. After that, further iteration is futile. You're spinning at EOS.

Comment: Nice catch, I didn't even see the outer loop :/